# I have several lists, each containing 206 elements. When I attempt to reference an index within those 206, I'm given an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several corresponding lists each containing exactly 206 elements. The number of elements and values of those elements can be different depending on what's inside the file the program reads.

One of those lists is comprised entirely of integers, and is used as the basis to determine if elements should be removed from all lists. My code follows:

```py
toRemove = []
for element in myList:
    if element < int(cutoff):  # cutoff is specified by the user
        toRemove.append(myList.index(element))
toRemove = [int(element) for element in toRemove]
for element in toRemove:
    del myList2[element]
    del myList3[element]
    ...
```

When I run `>>>len(myList)`, Python returns 206 for all lists, minus toRemove as toRemove is determined according to user input. However, when I use toRemove to remove those indexes from all lists Python greets me with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 104, in <module>
    del myList2[element]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The highest value in toRemove is 204 -- there are 205 indices in this list. toRemove does not contain any values lower than 0. Typecasting [element] into [int(element)] throws the same error.

The list of indexes to remove:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 45, 46, 47, 48, 51, 52, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 72, 73, 74, 75, 77, 80, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 124, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 133, 134, 135, 136, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 144, 145, 147, 149, 151, 110, 153, 154, 155, 157, 158, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 171, 173, 174, 175, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 192, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 200, 202, 203, 204]
```

As you can see, none less than 0 or greater than 205.

The list of numbers to check:

```
[1032, 3882, 4182, 6880, 1170, 1968, 2085, 3548, 9111, 1122, 11987, 12718, 7606, 8391, 8890, 2574, 1447, 6257, 1457, 11430, 7202, 6891, 1495, 12372, 12907, 2243, 3984, 11236, 3462, 4790, 1103, 1044, 8805, 1404, 6259, 8655, 13695, 6505, 3758, 2378, 3303, 3360, 9102, 14768, 12154, 3079, 3307, 2416, 7043, 9910, 10050, 6497, 2407, 13477, 4118, 13762, 1351, 3645, 4092, 3785, 1565, 3721, 4982, 4166, 11234, 7306, 3608, 2437, 4022, 2688, 11411, 9126, 3526, 1398, 5657, 2336, 8775, 4073, 14731, 8885, 7264, 8399, 10268, 12131, 2129, 11420, 1334, 3675, 1055, 3544, 5301, 6608, 1482, 14221, 2254, 4288, 1178, 5032, 4973, 19573, 3855, 4360, 6408, 3040, 3220, 11735, 3591, 3807, 2590, 6169, 2300, 1332, 8996, 6680, 3537, 1048, 3505, 5960, 3480, 1486, 4782, 4607, 18269, 8258, 4514, 8069, 5698, 1753, 6314, 1634, 3688, 9249, 18783, 5514, 1409, 7197, 3789, 8172, 2718, 5535, 3508, 1769, 2503, 8178, 2414, 1175, 13069, 1916, 12297, 1732, 69609, 3047, 2300, 5752, 1106, 1522, 11687, 3020, 3929, 9407, 13449, 4644, 2399, 4317, 4917, 5476, 1194, 4016, 1496, 7788, 9365, 1223, 12289, 1624, 1410, 3321, 12930, 1806, 7154, 4961, 2798, 5571, 1931, 7912, 4944, 10963, 2427, 7514, 2425, 2649, 1303, 13568, 2923, 11225, 5822, 4268, 5962, 2422, 6978, 12393, 1331, 12749, 7460, 1683, 6403, 11972]
```

You can substitute `cutoff` with 8000, as that is the number I am using to test the program.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I correct this problem?

Comment: since you use `del`, by the time you get to a higher index, it does not exist. try adding `print(len(myList2))` inside the loop to see what happens

Comment: Everytime you do `del`, `myList`s are decreasing in their size. And since `toRemove` contains the indices of _original list_ not the decreased size ones, its causing the problem.

Comment: @Chris How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: I would zip all lists, having the first (int-valued) list as the first list, then filter the list of tuples based on the first element of each tuple and unzip the filtered list of tuples back into several lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is that the list shrinks as you remove elements from it. Since you're removing them in order from front to back, the later indexes may end up being off the end of the list.

Consider this simpler scenario than your list with 200+ values:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3]
indexes_to_remove = [2, 3]

for i in indexes_to_remove:
    del lst[i]
```

You'll get the same exception as in your example. The reason is that after you remove index `2`, the last value (`3`) is *also* at index `2`, since the list got shorter.

There are a few ways to fix this. One option would be to remove the elements starting at the end of the list, and working forwards. That way the indexes you remove later on will always still be valid, as nothing before them will have been removed. Since you're guaranteed to be adding the indexes in order (more or less, see my note below), you can just iterate in reverse over them with `reversed`:

```
for element in reversed(toRemove):
    del myList2[element]
    del myList3[element]
```

Another option would be to compute a modified index as you go about removing some of the values from the lists. This is not too difficult:

```
for i, element in enumerate(toRemove):
    del myList2[element-i]
    del myList3[element-i]
```

Finally, it might be more efficient to rebuild your whole lists, rather than using `del` to remove some values from them. `del some_list[some_index]` takes `O(N)` time to complete, so even if you have to loop over the indexes to skip several times, it's probably going to be faster than doing a bunch of `del` operations:

```
toRemove = set(toRemove)
myList2 = [v for i, v in enumerate(myList2) if i not in toRemove]
myList3 = [v for i, v in enumerate(myList3) if i not in toRemove]
```

A final note: Your current code may have another error finding all the indexes to remove if `myList` can have multiple copies of the same values. That's because `myList.index(element)` will always find the *first* occurrence of the value `element`, even if you were just iterating over it when it appears later in the list. Instead you should probably use `enumerate` to get the indexes as you iterate:

```
for i, element in enumerate(myList):
    if element < int(cutoff):  # cutoff is specified by the user
        toRemove.append(i)
```

It might also be a good idea to change some of your variable names. You're currently using `element` for all your loops, and it sometimes refers to an index (in another list) and other times refers to a value. A more descriptive name would help distinguish between those cases!

Comment: Very thorough and informative answer! According to your last note, it could also be good idea to simply save elements instead of indices and use your list comprehension method without `enumerate`... something like `[v for v in myList3 if v not in toRemove]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo: no, that would have different semantics. The `toRemove` list (or set) gets built with indexes based upon the contents of `myList`, but the indexes are being used later to filter different lists (`myList2` and `myList3`). We don't know anything about the contents of those lists, only that their indexes correspond in some way to the indexes in the original list.

Answer (score 1):

As comments said, when you del something, the size of the list decreases and further elements shift (there's no gap).

What you can do is:

1. Use what you already used, but going from the highest index first.

2. Use your loop to *mark elements for deletion* (e.g. by assigning a None or other value not used in the list) rather than physically delete it - and after the loop filter them out (e.g. using `myList2 = [elem for elem in myList2 if elem]`).

3. Use list comprehension and avoid using loop altogether.

```
myList2 = [value for (index, value) in enumerate(myList2) if index not in toRemove]
```

Comment: Nice simple solution. An improvment can be to change `toRemove` to a set instead of alist. since checking for `in` fo a list is O(N) but with sets is much more efficient (O(1))...

Comment: Good point. I wasn't modifying toRemove creating part at all, only the deletion part but it should also be something to keep in mind!

Answer (score 1):

I would zip all lists, having the first (int-valued) list as the first list, then filter the list of tuples based on the first element of each tuple and unzip the filtered list of tuples back into several lists.

```
In [2]: list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
In [3]: list2 = list('abcde')
In [4]: list3 = list('12345')
In [5]: list(map(list, zip(*[x for x in zip(list1, list2, list3) if x[0] >= 3])))
Out[5]: [[3, 4, 5], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['3', '4', '5']]
```

Is it what you'd like to have?

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the list using `myList.sort(reverse=True)` solved my problem. Thanks!